# $D:L_{p_{[a,b]}}\to L_{p_{{[a,b]}}}$ bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis

> Consider $x(t)\in L_{p_{[a,b]}}$ and $a(t)\in L_{q_{[a,b]}}$. Then it is >defined the following operator $D:L_{p_{[a,b]}}\to L_{p_{{[a,b]}}}$ in which >$Dx(t)=a(t)x(t)$
> Let's prove that $D$ is bounded:
>
> $||Dx||_p=(\int_a^b|Dx(t)|^p dt)^{\frac{1}{p}}=(\int_a^b |a(t)|^p|x(t)|^p dt)^{\frac{1}{p}}\leqslant(\int_a^b |a(t)|^q dt)^{\frac{1}{q}}(\int_a^b|x(t)|^p dt)^{\frac{1}{p}}\leqslant \max_{a\leqslant t\leqslant b}|a(t)||x||_p$.

**Question**:

**1)** What did the author applied on this passage $(\int_a^b |a(t)|^p|x(t)|^p dt)^{\frac{1}{p}}\leqslant(\int_a^b |a(t)|^q dt)^{\frac{1}{q}}(\int_a^b|x(t)|^p dt)^{\frac{1}{p}}$? Hölder inequality(I do not see how)?

**2)** What about the last $ (\int_a^b |a(t)|^q dt)^{\frac{1}{q}}(\int_a^b|x(t)|^p dt)^{\frac{1}{p}}\leqslant \max_{a\leqslant t\leqslant b}|a(t)||x||_p$.
? Was it a mistake?

Comment: What book is this? I don't think the steps you have displayed are correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy This is no book. These are notes.

Comment: Please discard these notes. The inequalities are completely wrong.

Comment: How would you solve the problem?